# UITableView -> trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt -> UIContextualAction.image not centered correctly for rowHeights < 50

Tags: uitableview, uikit, uicontextualaction

I have a `UITableView` that has a different row height for the last column.
Each row has `UIContextualAction` to "mark as favourite" and "delete", represented by image (icons). It seams that when the row height is smaller then 50, the UIContextualAction.image placement is corrupted and no longer centered correctly:

[image: first row smaller then 50 height]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let (training, package) = decodeIndexPath(indexPath)           
        return package?.trainings.last == training ? 50 : 49
    }
    
    
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        guard let training = decodeIndexPath(indexPath).0 else { return nil }
        let imageSizeAction = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
        var actions = [UIContextualAction]()
        //add delete action (only custom exercises)
        if training.isCustom {
            let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: nil) { [weak self] (action, view, completion) in
                guard let training = self?.decodeIndexPath(indexPath).0 else { return }
            Database.shared.deleteCustom(training: training, completion: logAsError)
                completion(true)
            }
            deleteAction.image = PaintCode.imageOfBtnCellActionDelete(imageSize: imageSizeAction)
            actions.append(deleteAction)
        }
        //add to favorites
        let favoriteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: nil) { [weak self] (action, view, completion) in
            guard var training = self?.decodeIndexPath(indexPath).0 else { return }
            training.isFavorite = !training.isFavorite
            tableView.isEditing = false
            completion(true)
        }
        favoriteAction.backgroundColor = PaintCode.mainBlue
        let image = PaintCode.imageOfBtnCellActionFavorite(imageSize: imageSizeAction, selected: training.isFavorite)
        favoriteAction.image = image
        actions.append(favoriteAction)
        let action = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: actions)
        //only allow full swipe if delete is added
        action.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = actions.contains(where: {$0.style == .destructive})
        return action
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the `backgroundColor` and making a patternImage color I am able to get it centred correctly, however because of the tiling action you then get the icon repeated when you stretch the swipe. Not the wanted behaviour

```
favoriteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: PaintCode.imageOfBtnCellActionFavorite(imageSize:imageSize, selected: training.isFavorite))
```

So I see no other option then to have a min height of 50 points to make everything work reliably.